# Bound deg 3 partial differential operator on Laplace eigenfunction?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

I am no expert on PDE and analysis but I am looking for certain technique from PDE.
Let $D_2$ be the Laplace operator and $f$ is an eigenfunction, i.e., $D_2 f=\lambda f$ for some $\lambda>1$. (or even weakly $\lambda\gg 1$)

Let $D_3$ be a degree 3 partial differential operator, which may be explicitly written down. We assume that $D_3 f=\lambda_3 f$.
Is there any technique which may prove
$$|\lambda_3|\leq  c\lambda ^{3/2}$$ for some $c>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Under reasonable boundary conditions, you will have $$\|D_3f\|_{L^2}\le C\|f\|_{H^3}\le
C\|f\|_{H^4}^{1/2}\|f\|_{H^2}^{1/2}\le C\|\Delta^2f\|_{L^2}^{1/2}\|\Delta f\|_{L^2}^{1/2}\le C\lambda^{3/2}\|f\|_{L^2}.$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. but what is H^4 and H^3? are they sobolev norm? or the norm on Hardy space?

Comment: @Jeep Wrangler : it's the Sobolev norms

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a compact domain  $\Omega$in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you need to impose some elliptic boundary conditions  or  it is difficult to make predictions.   Assume for simlicity that $f$ satisfies the Dirichlet boundary conditions, i.e., it vanishes on the boundary of $\Omega$.    Then

$$\lambda_3\Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty}=\sup_{x\in\Omega} |D_3f(x)| \leq  C\lambda^{\frac{3}{2}} \Vert f\Vert_{L^2}\leq  C'\lambda^{\frac{3}{2}} \Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty}$$

This gives you

$$\lambda_3\leq C'  \lambda^{\frac{3}{2}}. $$

**Edit.** In my earlier post I misquoted the result I used. I have fixed the errors.    For details see my source X. Bin: *Derivatives of the spectral function  and Sobolev norms of eigenfunctions on a closed Riemann manifold*, Annal. Glob. Annalysis, vol. 26(2004), 231-252, Theorem 1.2.